# How to remove double quotes from json {"x":"y"} to {x:y} in php

Tags: php, json

How to remove double quotes from json  `{"x":"y"}` to `{x:y}` in PHP

Comment: put your sample code?

Comment: [{"x":"2020-02-20 09:14:06","y":"0"},{"x":"2020-02-20 09:14:06","y":"0"}]

Comment: I want {x:2020-02-20 09:14:06},{x:2020-02-20 09:14:06,y:0} in php

Comment: Himanshu Tyagi, pease [edit] to add that helpful information to the question, instead of hiding it down here in the comments.

Comment: You understand that your json is invalid by doing that? https://3v4l.org/O2Qsu

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you just need to remove " from a string you can use the str_replace method.

```
$new_str = str_replace("\"", "", json);
```

I hope I was helpful.

Comment: or even easier and better processing `str_replace('"', '', $json);`

Comment: Don't use text functions on json strings. What you have done here is destroyed a valid json making it invalid. https://3v4l.org/aVPBQ

Comment: @andreas I know that "manually" decoding a json is not the correct way of handling it. I just answered the question, I don't know which his purpose was, if he wanted to deserialise a json then its question was completely out of fouse.

Comment: If you don't know why they want it done then it's most likely a misunderstanding by OP. Just asking why and what purpose that needs to be done clears out any problems and you can answer the question for real. This answer is not an answer, and the question is not really a question either. It's certainly not helpful for anyone reading this.